# How to get the minimum relational scope for multiple input nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The statement below creates a representative data set in Neo4j.

I want to return the minimum relational graph for a given set of input nodes.

e.g., the minimum relational graph for the set of nodes "C", "G", "D" is "C, G, D"; and for "A", "E" it is "A, G, E".

The number of specific nodes is arbitrary, but require the returned scope is minimum.

How can this query be written?

### Sample Data

```
CREATE (A:Table {name:'A'})
CREATE (B:Table {name:'B'})
CREATE (C:Table {name:'C'})
CREATE (D:Table {name:'D'})
CREATE (E:Table {name:'E'})
CREATE (F:Table {name:'F'})
CREATE (G:Table {name:'G'})
CREATE
  (F)-[:Link]->(A),
  (A)-[:Link]->(G),
  (G)-[:Link]->(E),
  (G)-[:Link]->(C),
  (G)-[:Link]->(D),
  (E)-[:Link]->(B),
  (C)-[:Link]->(E)
```

[image: Data set]

Comment: this seems like a job for shortest path function... http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#single-shortest-path

Comment: shortest path only used for two nodes , it can't get the simplest relations with many input nodes

Answer (score 1):

Here is one simplistic solution. Generate the complete list of shortest paths between each pair of nodes in the set. Then reduce the resulting paths to the distinct set of nodes.

```
// set up the input nodes as a collection of attribute values to be matched
WITH ['C','G','D'] as inputs

// build a list of pairs that are not the same 
UNWIND RANGE(0,size(inputs)-1) as i
UNWIND RANGE(0,size(inputs)-1) as j
WITH CASE 
  WHEN i > j THEN [inputs[i],inputs[j]]
  ELSE null
END as pair

// find all of the shortest paths for each pair
MATCH p=allShortestPaths((a:Table {name: pair[0]})-[:Link*]-(b:Table {name: pair[1]}))
WITH p

// recollect the distinct nodes from the shortest paths
UNWIND nodes(p) as n
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT n) as min_relational_scope
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , it is not correct for some cases . for this case: CREATE (A:Table {name:'A'})
CREATE (B:Table {name:'B'})
CREATE (C:Table {name:'C'})
CREATE (D:Table {name:'D'})
CREATE
  (A)-[:Link]->(B),
  (B)-[:Link]->(C),
  (C)-[:Link]->(D),
  (D)-[:Link]->(A)   i may expect the result is "A,B,C" for the input nodes "A,B,C" , but it returned "A,B,C,D" .